# Passing map distance to ngModel in Ionic 2

Tags: google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

This is part of the code:

```
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {

  if((this.origin.query !== '') && (this.destination.query !== '')) {

    directionsService.route({
      origin: this.origin.query,
      destination: this.destination.query,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);    
        var total = 0;
        var route = directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          total += route.legs[i].distance.value;
        }

        total = total / 1000;

        this.distance = total << PROBLEM

      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }

  });

  } else {
    return;
}
```

This gets the route and distance in km (var total) between the two places. The problem is that I can't use the variable outside this callback. I want to bind it to a ngModel for further manual change / use.

I know that I need to use ngZone in order to update the model but I can't pass zone to the callback, some help ?^^

```
<ion-input type="number" (keyup)="onKey($event)" [(ngModel)]="distance"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not `ngZone` at all. It is the fact that you are using a regular function which changes `this` value. So `this.distance` within `function(response,status)` is different.
Try:

```
(response, status)=> {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);    
        var total = 0;
        var route = directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          total += route.legs[i].distance.value;
        }

        total = total / 1000;

        this.distance = total << PROBLEM

      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }

  }
```

Arrow Functions [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: True but still, even with the arrow function if I try to console.log(this.distance) outside the callback it will respond with undefined. that's where I got stuck.

Comment: depends on wether `.route` is an async function in which case, your console.log outside will print before the arrow function is executed.. in the case of the template, the view will get updated when the arrow function is called

Comment: looks like its working, thanks a lot.. I didn't check the view on every change I made, only the console :S thanks again ^^